# Doesn't print the entire string from sensor data

Tags: c++, arduino

So I have a setup of two sensors that captures a collection of data when I prompt it to.

```
void loop() {
..
    else if (serialString == "5")
    {
        String outputString = returnMeasurements(3);
    }
}
String returnMeasurements(int sensorType)
{
  if (sensorType == 1 || sensorType == 3)
  {
   //do assay
    String NIRString = "SOME DATA HERE" // Gather data from sensor and append to NIRSTRING
  }

  if (sensorType == 2 || sensorType == 3)
  {
    //do assay
    String VISString = "SOME DATA HERE" // Gather data from sensor and append to VISSTRING
  }
  Serial.print("TEST");
  Serial.print(NIRString + VISString); //HERE IS WHEN THINGS SOMETIMES GO WRONG
  return  NIRString + VISString;
}
```

I've simplified the above code a lot so that only the essential is available here.

My problem is, that sometimes, the `Serial.print` statement above the `return` statement doesn't print anything, even though `NIRString` and `VISString` contains data. (Meaning that nothing is returned)
It seems to happen randomly, but yet quite often.

I suspect, that since `NIRString` and `VISString` are quite long strings, it somehow occupy memory? Other than that, I have no idea what's wrong.

Comment: Utterly essential to answering this question is the type of `serialString`. If it is `std::string` what you've tried should work (assuming `Serial.print` will consume std::string`) if it is `char *` you are comparing pointers rather than comparing what's at the pointers and performing pointer arithmetic rather than concatenating the strings at the pointers.

Comment: oh, i overlooked that... guess i know why i got 3 downvotes now. jesus.

Comment: How do you even compile it. You've got several locally created variables and they cannot be used outside of its scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Variable shadowing.**
>
> In computer programming, variable shadowing occurs when a variable declared within a certain scope (decision block, method, or inner class) has the same name as a variable declared in an outer scope.

You haven't posted minimal working example and you've probably ommited global variables. But if you are able to compile it, it must be definitely there. DROP both global variable declarations: `String NIRString;` and `String VISString;`. It will not compile now. But that also means you were changing completely different variables inside of if block `{}`.

Keep the variables as local as possible. It cannot be inside of if () { block; }.

```
String returnMeasurements(int sensorType)
{
  String result;

  if (sensorType == 1 || sensorType == 3)
  {
    //do assay
    result += "SOME DATA HERE"; // Gather data from sensor and append to NIRSTRING
  }

  if (sensorType == 2 || sensorType == 3)
  {
    //do assay
    result += "SOME DATA HERE"; // Gather data from sensor and append to VISSTRING
  }
  Serial.print("TEST");
  Serial.print(result); //HERE IS WHEN THINGS SOMETIMES GO WRONG
  return result;
}
```

However this one is pretty memory intensive on Arduino platform, so it's not really reccomended at all to do String concatenations. Nice article about it: [The Evils od Arduino Strings](https://hackingmajenkoblog.wordpress.com/2016/02/04/the-evils-of-arduino-strings/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, in this case, I believe its the actual memory of the Arduino that bugs my result rather than variable shadowing. I will go ahead and read the article and see how I can optimize my code in that regard.

Comment: As it's here it' most definitely shadowing issue.